# OWIN + SignalR + Autofac

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, autofac

Taken from: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html:

"A common error in OWIN integration is use of the GlobalHost. In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch. You should not reference GlobalHost anywhere when using the OWIN integration."

That sounds reasonable. However, how should one resolve `IHubContext` from an ApiController, like the usual (non-OWIN):

`GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()`?

I can't find a reference on this one anywhere, and the only method I have by now is to register the `HubConfiguration` instance within the same container and do this:

```
public MyApiController : ApiController {
  public HubConfiguration HubConfig { get; set; } // Dependency injected by
                                                  // PropertiesAutowired()

  public IHubContext MyHubContext { 
    get { 
      return HubConfig
        .Resolver
        .Resolve<IConnectionManager>()
        .GetHubContext<MyHub>(); 
     } 
  }

  // ...

}
```

However, this seems quite verbose to me. What is the proper way to do it? To be more specific, is there a clean way to register `IConnectionManager`?

EDIT:

What I ended up doing is something like:

```
var container = builder.Build();
hubConfig.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container); 

app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfig);

var builder2 = new ContainerBuilder();
builder2
  .Register(ctx => hubConfig.Resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>())
  .As<IConnectionManager>();

builder2.Update(container);
```

but I have a feeling there must be an easier way to get that `IConnectionManager` injected in the controller.

Comment: It appears you also have Web API in the mix. Is that the case?

Comment: Can I ask why you are not doing constructor injection? Here you have huge dependecy to your container.

Comment: @TravisIllig: Yes, sorry if I wasn't explicit on that one. When I said ApiController i meant WebAPI controller.

Comment: @Anders I usually do, except for Web API controllers. I prefer having them with parameter-less constructors to allow for cleaner subclassing.

Comment: @itim What solution did you go with in the end?

Comment: @Matei_Radu: I went with what I wrote under the EDIT section. I hoped that someone would still suggest better alternative, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This answer is a little belated but here goes.

- I recommend strongly typed hubs.
- You need to add specific
  registrations for the strongly typed hubs.
- I don't use the
  GlobalHost

  - Instead I use the Configuration created for OWIN
    registration.

## Hub Declaration

```
public interface IMyHub
{
    // Any methods here for strongly-typed hubs
}

[HubName("myHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub<IMyHub>
```

## Hub Registration

From your Autofac registration

```
// SignalR Configuration
var signalRConfig = new HubConfiguration();

var builder = // Create your normal AutoFac container here

builder.RegisterType<MyHub>().ExternallyOwned(); // SignalR hub registration

// Register the Hub for DI (THIS IS THE MAGIC LINE)
builder.Register(i => signalRConfig.Resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub>()).ExternallyOwned();

// Build the container
var container = builder.Build();

// SignalR Dependency Resolver
signalRConfig.Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
app.MapSignalR("/signalr", signalRConfig);
```

## Resolving the hub in background code

Using AutoFacs AutowiredProperties() extension method then it can resolve the correct context (can also be in the constructor if you like).

```
public IHubContext<IMyHub> InstanceHubContext { get; [UsedImplicitly] set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant. I use slightly modified solution: `builder.RegisterType<AutofacDependencyResolver>().As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>().SingleInstance();` `builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>().Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub>()).ExternallyOwned();` and use autofac for resolve resolvers: `hubConfiguration.Resolver = container.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>();` The same for `httpConfiguration` for uniformity.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is to move some of this repeating code (I assume `IHubContext` is also used in some other classes and it is fetched in the same way) into container registration.

First thing is to register `IHubContext` instances, I assume you have multiple hubs in project. I that case, services have to be registered as [named services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services).

```
builder
    .Register<IHubContext>(c => c.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MyHub>())
    .Named<IHubContext>("MyHub");
```

Classes, which want to use `IHubContext` can now receive it as constructor parameter or as property. But we have to tell container which instance it should inject. This can be done in container configuration, in multiple ways

Constructor can use `ResolvedParameter` to correctly select `IHubContext` implementation

```
// example class 
public class SampleClass {
    public SampleClass(IHubContext context) { }
}

// and registration for this class
builder.RegisterType<SampleClass>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, ctx) =>
    {
        // only apply this to parameters of IHubContext type
        return pi.ParameterType == typeof(IHubContext);
    }, (pi, ctx) =>
    {
        // resolve context
        return ctx.ResolveNamed<IHubContext>("MyHub");
    }));
```

Property injection, is also a bit tricky. It is needed to resolve correct instance in `OnActivated` callback, for example like this:

```
// example class
public class SampleClass2
{
    public IHubContext Context { get; set; }
}

// registration for this case
builder.RegisterType<SampleClass2>()
    .PropertiesAutowired()
    .OnActivated(e => e.Instance.Context = e.Context.ResolveNamed<IHubContext>("MyHub"));
```

Comment: This looks cleaner, but still a little too verbose and I have a feeling there might be an easier way. My example is somewhat simplified, but what I would really want to have is IConnectionManager instance injected into controllers if possible (right now I cannot do that without updating Autofac container after building it, like: `var connManager = hubConfig.Resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>(); builder.Register(ctx => connManager); builder.Update(container)`. Trying: `builder.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IConnectionManager>())` does not work for me.

Comment: Ah, I wrongly assumed, that all SignalR internals are registered in Autofac container. In fact, `AutofacDependencyResolver` delegate construction of internal SignalR components to `DefaultDependencyResolver` which comes from SignalR itself. So your approach looks valid and is in line with examples by Microsoft (this one is for Ninject but looks similar to what you are doing http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection). Another option would be to register also internal SignalR services in container, but that might bring maintenance issues during SignalR updates.

Answer (score 2):

I did similar to yourself, which got it working in Owin for me

```
builder.RegisterInstance(config.Resolver).As<IDependencyResolver>();
builder.Update(container);
```

Then use this to get my hub

```
Resolve<IDependencyResolver>().Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MyHub>();
```

Hope this helps others out there

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I could find is somehow a mix between the answers here, but to me seems the best way to handle this and maintain best practices for both SignalR and Autofac SignalR Integration:

In the classes that I want a hub context I have a property

```
 public IConnectionManager ConnectionManager { get; set; }
```

which I register as following:

```
 newBuilder.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>());
```

where `resolver` is a `new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);`

Then, I basically use the `ConnectionManager` very similar to `GlobalHost`:

```
var context = ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<WorkshopsHub>();
```

then I call `context.Clients.All.clientMethod();`

This way I am easily able to update clients from outside the hub, have easily maintainable code and follow the best practices (I think and hope:D).

I also thought of registering and resolving them at Startup, but it seems like a very  difficult task to do, with very little benefit (other than feeling good when it succeeds).

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214891/1462615) on the question [How to configure Autofac and SignalR in a MVC 5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511095/how-to-configure-autofac-and-signalr-in-a-mvc-5-application/49214891#49214891).

Since I was running in either an IIS Site OR a self hosted site I ran into another issue. I created all the hubs and controllers in a shared dll and then referenced that dll.
Which caused Autofac's SignalR `IAssemblyLocator` to not bring back the required assemblies. So I registered the `DefaultAssemblyLocator` in the container.

The rest is making sure that:

- `Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver` is resolved as a singlton and used as the `HubConfiguration.Resolver`
- `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager` is resolved as a singlton and injected where required - in the `MessageService` in this example

[Here](https://gist.github.com/matthewvukomanovic/5f174946e21c4fe4e327ebc51fd7dc4a) is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewvukomanovic/5f174946e21c4fe4e327ebc51fd7dc4a) with the entire required file and comment on required NuGet Package installs

The working example follows:

```
public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // What ever registrations you need here

        // IMessageService interacts with the hub
        builder.RegisterType<MessageService>().As<IMessageService>();

        // Register the controllers and the hubs
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(ServiceModule).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(ServiceModule).Assembly);

        // Register the default Assembly Locator since otherwise the hub will no be created by Signalr correctly IF it is NOT in the entry executables assembly.
        builder.RegisterType<DefaultAssemblyLocator>().As<IAssemblyLocator>();

        // Register Autofac resolver into container to be set into HubConfiguration later
        builder.RegisterType<Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Register ConnectionManager as IConnectionManager so that you can get
        // hub context via IConnectionManager injected to your service
        builder.RegisterType<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.IConnectionManager>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform the configuration 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The application builder to configure.</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
        var container = builder.Build();

        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container),
#if DEBUG
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always,
#endif
        };

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration()
        {
#if DEBUG
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
#endif
        };
        hubConfig.Resolver = container.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>();

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfig);
    }
}

public interface IMessageService
{
    void BroadcastMessage(string message);
}

public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;

    public MessageService(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
    {
        _hubContext = connectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
    }

    public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.Message(message);
    }
}

public interface IMessage
{
    void Message(string message);
}

public class MessageHub : Hub<IMessage>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public MessageHub(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public void Message(string message)
    {
        Clients.Others.Message(message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Clients.Others.Message("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stoppedCalled)
    {
        Clients.Others.Message("Client disconnected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stoppedCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work if my service is in another project, same solution?