# Add SignalR's ITransportHeartbeat to Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, signalr, autofac

I'm trying to use Autofac to have one instance of the [ITransportHeartbeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj919061(v=vs.118)) interface for my ASP.NET MVC 5 app to track all connected users. I use the `ITransportHeartbeat` interface to determine if a user's connection is still active. To do this, I need to have one instance of the SignalR hub for the app by using Autofac.

The challenge: when I run the app, it never hits the overridden `OnConnected()`, `OnReconnected()`, or `OnDisconnected()` in the SignalR hub. However, the client's `hub.start()` is hit and I see the `Hub Started` message when the page loads:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("Hub Started");
});
```

If I add a parameterless constructor to the hub, it does hit them, but then the `ITransportHeartbeat` interface is null and that defeats the point of injecting the interface into the hub.

I've referenced the following for help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214891/177416
- https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476106/177416
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126852/177416

Here is `Startup.cs`:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
            .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .InstancePerRequest();

        var signalRConfig = new HubConfiguration();
        builder.RegisterType<MonitoringHubBase>().ExternallyOwned();

        builder.RegisterType<Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()
            .SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(context => 
            context.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()
            .Resolve<IConnectionManager>()
            .GetHubContext<MonitoringHubBase, IMonitoringHubBase>())
            .ExternallyOwned();
        builder.RegisterType<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportHeartbeat>()
            .SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        signalRConfig.Resolver = container
            .Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>();

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", signalRConfig);

        config.DependencyResolver = 
            new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver((IContainer)container);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Here is the hub from which the other hubs derive:

```
public interface IMonitoringHubBase
{
    Task OnConnected();
    Task OnReconnected();
    Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled);
}

public abstract class MonitoringHubBase : Hub<IMonitoringHubBase>
{
    private ITransportHeartbeat Heartbeat { get; }

    public MonitoringHubBase(ITransportHeartbeat heartbeat)
    {
        Heartbeat = heartbeat;
    }

    public MonitoringHubBase()
    {
    }

    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        // Add connection to db...
    }

    public override async Task OnReconnected()
    {
        // Ensure connection is on db...
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        // Remove connection from db...
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod(int id)
    {
        // Heartbeat object used here...
    }
}
```

And here's one of the hubs that inherits from the base hub:

```
[HubName("MyHub")]
public class MyHub : MonitoringHubBase
{
    public MyHub(ITransportHeartbeat heartbeat) : base(heartbeat)
    {
    }

    public MyHub()
    {   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution! Removed the parameterless c'tor from the hub and modified `Startup.cs` to this; hope this helps the next person struggling with this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
            .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportHeartbeat>()
            .SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver>()
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()
            .SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var signalRConfig = new HubConfiguration();
        signalRConfig.Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container),
            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver((IContainer)container);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

With help from this article: https://kwilson.io/blog/get-your-web-api-playing-nicely-with-signalr-on-owin-with-autofac/